# How to convert a decompiled .mdb file to .mde file in ms access

Tags: ms-access-2016

The windows and Ms Access is upgraded to new version. So we faced the issue of module not found error while running the application. As suggested by some of them I have decompiled the application. But the problem I am facing is, application is working only when it is decompiled. Now I want to create a .mde file and facing the same error module not found when converting the .mdb file to .mde file.

Comment: The versions are office 365 and ms access 2016

Comment: it looks like you haven't isolated the issue, that is what you need to find out. your mdb may be corrupt. what errors do you get when you actually try to compile the app from the VB Editor window in the mdb, after you decompliled? you need to solve those issue before you attempt to create a mde. and since you are on office 365, you may want to upgrade you mdb's to accdb and once you sort out the problem, create accde's which is the equivalent of mde in older version